# Does the inbuilt Ninject assembly loaders have error handling

Tags: c#, plugins, dependency-injection, ninject

I've written a plugin manager so

```
public class WeinCadPluginManager : NinjectModule, IEnableSerilog
{
    public override void Load()
    {

        var codeBaseUrl = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        var codeBasePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(codeBaseUrl.AbsolutePath);
        var dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(codeBasePath);
        Debug.Assert(dirPath != null, "dirPath != null");
        var path = dirPath;

        var types = Directory
            .GetFiles(path, "*.dll")
            .Select (Assembly.LoadFile)
            .SelectMany (assembly =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return assembly.GetExportedTypes();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        this.Serilog()
                            .Error
                            (e, "Failed to load assembly {assembly}", assembly);
                        return new Type[]
                        {
                        };
                    }
                })
            .Where(type=>typeof(IWeinCadPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var assembly in types)
        {
            Kernel.Bind<IWeinCadPlugin>().To(assembly).InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this pretty much duplicates

```
Kernel.Load("*.dll")
```

except if there are any errors exporting the types from an assembly then `Kernel.Load` crashes with no error handling possible. I wouldn't want the failure to load a single plugin assembly to crash my app. Is my solution the only viable way or does Ninject have some error handling available?

Answer (score 1):

I think a `try { } catch { }` around each `Kernel.Load("specificplugin.dll")` should suffice.
You would still have to find all the assemblies yourself, but would have to write less code.

```
var codeBaseUrl = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
var codeBasePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(codeBaseUrl.AbsolutePath);
var dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(codeBasePath);

var dllPaths = Directory.GetFiles(dirpath, "*.dll");

foreach(string dllPath in dllPaths)
{
     try
     {
         kernel.Load(dllPath);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         this.Serilog()
             .Error(e, "Failed to load assembly {assembly}", assembly);
     }
}
```

Drawback: ninject must be adding the binding to the kernel either on `.Bind()` or on `.To(..)`, because all the rest of the fluent syntax methods are optional. So if there would be an exception in the `.When()`, `.InScope()`,.. any other optional method, you would be left with a non-complete binding and thus, most likely, a faulty software.

(However i suspect that most errors will not materialize when creating the binding, but rather when activating the binding. And you are not protected against that.)

As far as i know there is no way to remove bindings from ninject once you've added them. Except for the `.Rebind()` - but that is always replacing a binding with a different one.
So no, i don't think there's something like "rollback on exception".

So we must be looking for an alternative solution. There is one: child kernels. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel

Load each plugin into it's own child kernel. in case the fooplugin.dll load fails, dispose the child kernel. In case it works.. well you're good to go! :)
This also has the advantage that plugin's can't influence one another. Imagine two plugins would do `IBindingRoot.Bind<string>().ToConstant("some constant")` ;-)

(please note that i haven't tested whether disposing the child kernel before the parent kernel works "as expected", so you should test it out first. Simple enough, right?)